# Redirect only pdf files from html site to new wordpress directory using redirection plugin and regex

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, pdf, redirect

I want to redirect just **PDF**s that are found under the root directory of the old html site to a specific WordPress uploads directory. But I need to make sure that I don’t end up sending **all** pages/files at the root level to the uploads directory.

So I want it to do something like this:

**From** `http://www.oldsite.com.au/*.pdf`
**To** `https://www.newsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/*.pdf`

I know that is the incorrect format, but I am using the above example to show that I want the redirect to pickup all files that end with .pdf, and redirect them to the same file name at the new location.

I am using the WordPress redirection plugin to do the regex redirection.

Here is a regex example that moves **all files** from root to the selected directory.

```
Source URL: ^/(.*)
Target URL: https://www.newsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/$1
```

What I would like help on is how to adjust the Source URL to **select only PDF files**, and then pass on the full filename to the Target URL (including the .pdf extension)

### UPDATE:

I thought I had figured out a way that might work for me.

```
Source URL: ^/(.*).pdf
Target URL: https://www.newsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/$1.pdf
```

It does work correctly as I wanted it to for this kind of url: http://www.oldsite.com/abc.pdf

But unfortunately it is also picking up this kind of URL, and basically giving it an infinite redirection loop; http://www.oldsite.com/dir1/dir2/abc.pdf

I had thought that putting the ^ before the / would limit it to just the root directory, and not pickup all subsequent directories also. But I guess the (.*) is where it is allowing anything in the url that appears before the .pdf (including directories).

Can anyone give me an example of how to **stop it looking beyond the root directory** for a PDF?

**NOTE**: The regex for the SOURCE URL needs the *relative* URL that you want to redirect from.

**ADDITIONAL NOTE**: The plugin "Redirection" uses PHP’s regular expressions. These are commonly known as PCRE, and may not be exactly the same as other regular expression libraries.

Thanks for any advise!
SunnyOz

Comment: Do you mean like this `https?://\S+/([^\s/]+\.pdf)$` with a capture group, where the filename is in group 1 using  `$1` see https://regex101.com/r/JkalPR/1

Comment: The plugin "Redirection" uses PHP’s regular expressions. These are commonly known as PCRE, and may not be exactly the same as other regular expression libraries.  However, I think you have the right idea, but I can't figure out how to change what you wrote to what the plugin requires.  The Source URL only needs to start with the root slash (ie: doesn't need to include http, etc). Can you rewrite you example for me?  I need to make sure that the expression doesn't pick up subsequent directories.

Comment: Thanks @Thefourthbird!!  Actually your suggested did work with a few tweaks.  I used this version for the SOURCE URL regex: '^\/([^\s\/]+\.pdf)' and that seems to do the trick.  Would you like to put your comment as the answer, so I can accept it?  I am not really sure why it works, because I don't understand the '^\s\/' part, so I would like to know what code is responsible for not allowing the extra directories to be picked up.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a capture group after matching the leading forward slash:

```
^\/([^\s\/]+\.pdf)
```

If you can use a different delimiter than `/` you don't have to eacape the backslash.

```
^/([^\s/]+\.pdf)
```

See a [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2L0cjQ/1)

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `/` Match literally
- `(` Capture group 1

  - `[^\s/]+` Negated charater class, match 1+ times any char except a whiteapace char or `/`
  - `\.pdf` Match `.pdf`
- `)` Close group 1

If you want to assert the end of the string, you can add `$` to the end of the pattern.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! 

For those that want to see the final setup for the Redirection plugin: 

Source URL: ^\/([^\s\/]+\.pdf)
Target URL: https://www.newsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/$1